# Can increasing thread count degrade the overall performance in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a application in java springs. The application requires multithreading. So I am using callable & executor service since each thread will be returning some string value.
So my question is how can I decide the maximum thread count that can be kept?
And the important question is if I keep on increasing thread count but taking care the condition of heap size, does that start degrading the performance after thread count crosses some limit?

Comment: probably. best way to find out is by trying ;)

Comment: The section "8.2. Sizing Thread Pools" in "Java Concurrency in Practice" has useful information on this topic http://books.google.ru/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&pg=PT186&lpg=PT186&dq=Sizing+Thread+Pools+java+concurrency+in+practice&source=bl&ots=un0Gx2sRlr&sig=q6gBylm5pFXWgdyB3bV6KcIQUsI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LsRkU4vDHcGN4ATvx4C4Dw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the best answer to such questions is "It depends". But I can definitely point out, on what it depends :)

- The work you are doing in a thread.
- Is the code already exploiting the parallel nature of the underlying hardware?
- Is there a bottleneck in the whole code, which will take more time than the parallel tasks?

Obtaining the Thread infrastructure in the JVM is a costly process, the moment you talk of threads, synchronization also comes into picture. Lets forget about synchronization for a while. Even then if the task being performed has a lower over head than the overhead of allocating and managing threads,  I would say a strict NO to multi threading.

- Things were multi-threading proves to be a boon is when your primary task is to make a network call and there are numerous such tasks.
- Another such requirement is doing some independent calculations like block wise matrix multiplications.

**Note**: Compilers now a days do some optimization to improve the parallel processing capabilities of your code. But the bigger responsibility of coding it the right way is up to you.

For e.g.: Consider the below code to add 10 numbers in an array.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    total += a[i];
}
```

This might seem the best way to add elements of an array. But the below is actually exploiting the parallel processing capabilities of the processor:

```
total = a[0] = a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5] + a[6] + a[7] + a[8] + a[9];
```

Choose wisely :)

Comment: Thanks :). That was a quite helpful information.
So can i summarize it and say "yes, there is a possibility that the performance may degrade with increasing number of threads if you do not choose it wisely"??

Comment: Yes of course... mostly it is bad in case of smaller tasks. 
It is really good when the tasks are time consuming and can be done in parallel

Comment: The compiler is more than capable of doing the code transformation you point out in your note itself. Doing this stuff by hand is rarely a good idea - certainly not in this case

Answer (score 4):

The best way to figure out how many threads to use is empirically. But you can guess in advance; If you're doing a lot of blocking IO you'll want more threads. If you're not doing any IO at all and are just using CPU, then you ideally don't want more threads than you have cores. You'll also have to consider synchronization overhead, if you require lots of synchronization there's a good chance that running that code on multiple threads isn't going to improve performance.

Again, it depends a lot on the application though. These are all just rules of thumb, you'll have to perform a more detailed analysis and some test runs to be actually able to tell for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I appreciate. :)
I understood the thing, "running that code on multiple threads isn't going to improve performance.". But even if it does not improve the performance, can it degrade the performance with increasing number of threads?

Comment: @Abhijit If you're doing it wrong, yes. If you have too many threads you may end up having to do lots of unnecessary context switches, which are quite costly in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely yes, this will decrease the overall performance. Here are some facts to consider:

- In most cases you have limited number of threads can be run concurrently because of limited number of CPUs/cores;
- Putting one thread to `WAITING` state together with activating some other thread, which is part of so-called `context switching` is quite expensive in terms of CPU resoures;
- There is **Amdahl's law** which provides answer to the question - what is the relation between number of threads, CPUs, part of "work" can be done concurrently and the resulting speedup. It's hard to post formula here, so I just leave [wiki page link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes, because swapping between threads is quite expensive. You have to strike a balance between swapping out threads that are waiting so other threads can get some CPU with the expense of the swap.

For example, if you had 100 comsumer threads for a typical producer I doubt the throughput would be much greater than if you had 10.